Selecionar en donde ingresar datos desde un textbox
Hola:Me pregunto si es posible ingresar datos desde un formulario pero elijiendo en donde.
Es decir; selecionar desde un textbox2 en donde ingresar el dato, ejemplo el valor de un textbox1 pero tambien eleijiendo el rango desde otro textbox2 si en el textbox2 aparece A:1 que ahi se inserte el dato o si aparece AG20 que ahi se inserte el dato. De antemano mucas gracias

Hola, está  algo confusa tu pregunta. Lee Cómo preguntar para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de bienvenida para entender mejor cómo funciona el sitio y de paso obtener tu primera medalla!

Sí, si se puede. Puedes controlarlo todo con macros en VBA, pero tendrás que aprender a programar en dicho lenguaje.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
